# How to use web server with iOS app?

Tags: ios, web, ssh

I searching few days but I can not find any tutorial how can I do this. I got ip address, ssh-login, ssh-pass and server on .com , I need to make in-app registration and in-app login via previous registration on this server. How can I do this? I need any tutorial, samples or good frameworks to do this, and I will be very thankful if someone explain me basics on this type of work. Thank you, sorry for my english.

UPDATE
I find this https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer library, can it be helpful for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would post some code here for you, but since you're looking specifically for tutorials, try this one out.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/ios-tutorial-part-1-creating-a-web-service/#.

I'm pretty sure you can find some great tutorials, just google "iOS REST tutorial".

Comment: @user3196922 I looked, but couldn't find one..this is another good example... http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

Comment: can you help me here too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149382/how-to-use-web-server-with-ios-app-sample