# How to use web server with iOS app? sample

Tags: ios, json, web, ssh, request

I write similar question and I got answere on 'How to use web server with iOS app?' but I need sample because it is more simple for me to have some sample how this works, for example can you help me with that sample:

how can I implement request on my server for exhample if I want /register new user and I will   receive the server's answere in JSON and I need to send it it POST in variable 'data' ? For exhample server is http://myserver.com:8080.

```
{ 
 email:
 password:
}  //this is register form but  how named this field?
```

I wiil receive answere like this :

```
{
result:[OK|fail]
 message: [error if fail]
 data: [if OK]
}
```

I need sample how can I send and receive /register request. Sorry for my english, it comes better :)

UPDATE Also I can not understand how can I use this forms in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here you have my temple to send Login req, I have implemented AFNetworking(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and NSJSONSerialization for parsing Json response. It is hard to give you a sample code, but I think if you customize this piece of code everything should work fine.

```
        - (void)sentLoginReqWithLogin:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)pass {

            NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : email,
                                     @"password" : pass
                                     };


            AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOST_URL]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:POST
                                                                    path:LOGIN_URL
                                                              parameters:params];


            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //HERE YOU HAVE A RESPONSE (your server answer)
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {         
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);      
            }];


            [operation start];

}
```

Comment: ok, I will try, and can you give some adding if I need to add O-Auth-token I will insert it in NSDictionary *params ?

Comment: Yes, see this hint:  
`NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" :  @"token_string",
                             @"email" : log,
                             @"password" : pass
                             };`

Comment: ok, thanks, do you recommend to use AFNetworking then other libs?

Comment: How can I sent the post request in variable "data"? I use this, but got response that data in null :  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"/login"
                                                      parameters:params];

Comment: You send POST request correctly, maybe the params are created in wrong way, what structure of params is required by your backend. I guess that is only example: `{ 
 email:
 password:
}  //this is register form but  how named this field?`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Post data to server
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/register/"]];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString * bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&username=%@&password=%ld", "username", "password"];
[request setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection * urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


// On server, do this (assuming PHP)
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

// Do w/e checks you need to do against the username and password, be sure to hash and salt the password
// Store user information in database
```

Comment: Is there server's answere?

Comment: @user3196922 you'll need to implement the NSURLConnection delegate methods to get the response.